# Swift Closures in for loop

Tags: swift

Currently I am having code which executes a closure inside a loop. I want to know when all the closures have finished executing. Currently I am using a counter and incrementing it when the closure is completed and then I compare it with the no of times to be executed. Code is below

```
var count = 0
var noOfTimes = 10
for i in 0..<noOfTimes {
    someVariable.someClosure {
        result in
        count = count + 1
        if count == noOfTimes {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this without the counter.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the closure executed synchronously or asynchronously? – Note that the condition  `if count == noOfTimes` will *never* be true because the loop executes only `noOfTimes-1` times.

Comment: Its asynchronously executed.  The if code was a mistake, just wanted to convey my point. I will change it now

Comment: Why don't you use promises? Something like https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit ? This doesn't address the original question but perhaps it's what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @eipipuz I did look at promises. But didn't want to add a whole new framework for a simple task. I am wondering whether there is a simple way to achieve this in the swift language itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a `DispatchGroup` for this.  It works like a counted semaphore.  You can increase the count by calling `enter` and decrease the count by calling `leave`.  You can schedule a closure to be executed when the count reaches 0 using `notify`:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
var noOfTimes = 10
for i in 0..<noOfTimes {
    dispatchGroup.enter()  //  Enter the dispatch group
    someVariable.someClosure {
        result in
        // Process result
        ...
        dispatchGroup.leave() // Exit dispatch group
    }
}
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    print("All Done")
})
```

Comment: This helped me a lot.