# Execute swift-closure in while loop

Tags: swift, asynchronous

**The goal**

I want to be able to loop through a while-loop generating random numbers. Per iteration one random number, if it doesn't work, another iteration. And so on. I want to get a random user from my database which has to fulfill three conditions. (They are listed at the bottom of the loop).

**Challenge**

How can I make sure my code executes in the right sequence?

1. Generate random number
2. Get user from database
3. Do we want the user?

   A) Yes. Exit while-loop

   B) No. Start at 1. again. We want another user

My results:

```
static func getRandomUser() {
        var randomNumberID = 1
        var UID = ""
        var current_user: User? = nil

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue")
        let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        dispatchQueue.async {
            repeat {
                dispatchGroup.enter()

                // Randomly select one user
                randomNumberID = Int.random(in: 1...Internet.all_time_user_count)

                // Transform generated number to uid with which we can retrieve the user from the database
                // E.g. "1" -> "iosdnaui29pbpqwbdabd"
                Internet.getUIDOfUser(with: String(randomNumberID)) { (uid) in

                    UID = uid

                    // Download user from database
                    Internet.getUser(with: uid) { (user) in
                        current_user = user

                        dispatchSemaphore.signal()
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                }

                dispatchSemaphore.wait()

                /// Stay in the loop until we find a user
                /// 1. Whom we don't have yet            `Internet.contains(uid: UID, in: discover_users)`
                /// 2. Who exists in the database        `current_user == nil`
                /// 3. Who wants to be found              `current_user?.discoverable == false`
            } while(current_user == nil || current_user?.discoverable == false || Internet.contains(uid: UID, in: discover_users))

            // I want to execute the following line of code when I know that I found an user with the conditions of the while loop
            discover_users.append(current_user!)
        }

        // Do I need another dispatchGroup like this which notifies me when the whole while-loop is finished?
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: dispatchQueue) {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Another loop iteration finished")
            }
        }
    }
```

Source on which my current code is based one:

[Swift Closures in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298808/swift-closures-in-for-loop)

Comment: You want to achieve synchronus better to make serial queue and do all your task inside serial queue.

Comment: I'm confused with your usage of semaphores. Why do you even need semaphores? Also, I think you're not using them properly.

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Can you write an answer with your idea?

Comment: @Roberto I have it from an answer on stack overflow. I left it like this. I will remove it if it really doesn't make a difference

Comment: I'd get rid of the async dispatch and the semaphores. I don't see why are those necessary at all. The rest of the code seems to be fine, but you might have issues if the closure for the DB is an escaping closure.

Comment: I got rid of it. DB is escaping too tho

Comment: I just noticed that the semaphores make a difference. Without them the print statement is not executed and it never calls the line `current_user = user`